# VIsual Studio 2010 is very slow opening a solution after installing SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Yesterday I installed SP1 on my Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and I'm not sure if this is cause or correlation, but since then VS takes forever to open a solution. The "Preparing solution" dialogue has been showing for about 15 minutes now. Last night, after SP1, it wasn't as long, but it did take about 5 minutes to 'prepare the solution'. Anyone know anything about such issues with SP1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me : Try CTRL-ALT-SHIFT J twice. It calls the garbadge collector of the CLR gfx interface.

Comment: How did you find this arcane little tip out?